# scheduling jobs using python apscheduler

Tags: python, process, cron, monitoring, scheduling

I have to monitor a process continuously and I use the process ID to monitor the process. I wrote a program to send an email once the process had stopped so that I would manually reschedule it, but often I forget to reschedule the process ( basically another python program). I then came across the apscheduler module and used the cron style scheduling ( http://packages.python.org/APScheduler/cronschedule.html) to spawn a process once it has stopped. Now, I am able to spawn the process once PID of the process has been killed, but when I spawn it using the apscheduler I am not able to get the process id (PID) of the newly scheduled process; Hence, I am not able to monitor the process. Is there a function in apscheduler to get the process ID of the scheduled process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of relying on APSchedule to return the pid, why not have your program report the pid itself. It's quite common for daemons to have pidfiles, which are files at a known location that just contain the pid of the running process. Just wrap your main function in something like this:

```
import os

try:
    with open("/tmp/myproc.pid") as pidfile:
        pidfile.write(str(os.getpid()))
    main()
finally:
    os.remove("/tmp/myproc.pid")
```

Now whenever you want to monitor your process you can firstly check to see in the pid file exists, and if it does, retrieve the pid of the process for further monitoring. This has the benefit of being independent of a specific implementation of cron, and will make it easier in future if you want to write more programs that interact with the program locally.